# get folders from a directory and run them with sigheck64 for all those folders and save results to file

Tags: powershell

I am trying to list all folders in a directory and run sigcheck with path to loop all those $folders. example sigcheck64 checkthisdirectory/$folders/download

```
$directory = dir E:\Users -Directory | Select BaseName
$SigcheckPath="C:\Windows\temp\sigcheck.exe"

foreach ($dir in $directory){
& $SigcheckPath -nobanner -a -h -s -vt -c E:\Users\$directory\Downloads > C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\$directory.csv }
```

first script should get all folders found in specified directory E:\Users

and try them with sigcheck for all the directory in above folder then save results to a .csv having the specific $directory names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues in your script currently:

```
$directory = dir E:\Users -Directory | Select BaseName
```

This will create new objects with a `BaseName` property, rather than just returning the `BaseName` strings directly to `$directory`, so change that to:

```
$directory = dir E:\Users -Directory | Select -Expand BaseName
```

Inside the `foreach()` loop you should refer to `$dir` (the current item in the loop) rather than `$directory` (which is the entire array we're iterating over):

```
foreach ($dir in $directory){
  & $SigcheckPath -nobanner -a -h -s -vt -c E:\Users\$dir\Downloads > C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\$dir.csv 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, It has worked perfectly. I have edited code for it to do multiple directories now although it creates too many files.  ```$directory = dir E:\Users -
foreach ($dir in $directory){

  & $SigcheckPath -nobanner -a -h -s -c E:\Users\$dir\$path1 > C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\$dir-$path1-01.csv | & $SigcheckPath -nobanner -a -h -s -c E:\Users\$dir\$path2 > C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\$dir-$path2-01.csv
}
{
Get-Content C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\$dir-$path1-01.csv, C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\$dir-$path2-01.csv |
  Select-Object -Unique |
    Set-Content -Encoding ASCII joined.csv
    }```

Comment: Is there a way I could merge all the files together?

Answer (score 0):

To merge all together (also incorporating suggestions from the accepted answer):

```
$directory = dir E:\Users -Directory | Select -Expand BaseName
$SigcheckPath="C:\Windows\temp\sigcheck.exe"

$title = $null
$allLines = @()

foreach ($dir in $directory){
    Write-Host "inspecting $dir ..."
    $csv = (& $SigcheckPath -nobanner -a -h -s -vt -c E:\Users\$dir\Downloads | tee C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\$dir.csv)
    $title, $lines = $csv
    $allLines += $lines
}

$($title; $allLines) | Out-File -Encoding utf8  C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\all.csv
```

You'll get a single `all.csv`, and also a separate file for each dir (remove `| tee ...` if you don't want that)